# Reactjs Mobx @action function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, mobx

I've just started using mobx. I have mobx class as follows:

```
class Store{
@observable locationKey = null;
@observable query = '';

@action setLocationKey = key =>{
    this.locationKey = key;
}
@action setQuery = test =>{
    this.query = test;
}
}
```

I have two observable properties, and I have two actions that can alter these properties. As far as I know, I can only change the observable properties through the action, and I cannot directly change, for example, `this.props.store.locationKey = 5` in some other component ( Am I right?)

Then if I have like 100 observable properties and I wish to change them, do I have to make each action for each observables? That would be really inefficient. Is there way to make one function so that all observables can share in order to alter the properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can make such a function in your store class to handle your hundreds of `@observable` properties.

```
@action setProperty = (key, value) => {
    this[key] = value;
}
```

And for your first question, you can change an `@observable` directly, but using an `@action` function is the best practice. So just keep using `@action` functions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try this!!